# Gulp не создает папку назначения (dist)?

Tags: gulp, gulp4

Подскажите пожалуйста новичку, как, почему Gulp не создает папку назначения (dist).
Одну проблему решил, ошибок уже нет, а папку не хочет создавать.
На скринах все видно, подскажите, где проблема либо что нужно поправить?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась заменой прямых кавычек на обратные.

Вместо:

```
'${buildFolder}/files/'
'${srcFolder}/files/**/*.*'
```

надо:

```
`${buildFolder}/files/`
`${srcFolder}/files/**/*.*`
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! если вы заинтересованы в ответе на данный вопрос, то [зарабойтайте репутацию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) и объявите [конкурс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) на этот вопрос. а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст ответа можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа.